# change background image of buttons(each with its indivisual id) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried to create a voting system similar to that in reddit. Each post have two buttons, and each button associated with specific post have different id. I have set the image of all the buttons as uncolored arrow.

```
<div class="details">
<li>AAAAA</li></div>
<div id="voting">
    <div class="vote-up"><button id="up-e/aaaaa" title="Up"  class="up "  onclick="vote('e/aaaaa', 1,'swap')"  ></button>
    </div>
    <div id="vote-score">
    <div id="score-e/aaaaa"><span>51</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="vote-down"><button id="down-e/aaaaa" title="Down" class="down" onclick="vote('e/aaaaa', 0, 'swap')"  ></button>
    </div></div>

 </div>
<div id="content">

<div class="details">
<li>MIT</li></div>
<div id="voting">
    <div class="vote-up"><button id="up-e/mit" title="Up"  class="up "  onclick="vote('e/mit', 1,'swap')"  ></button>
    </div>
    <div id="vote-score">
    <div id="score-e/mit"><span>40</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="vote-down"><button id="down-e/mit" title="Down" class="down" onclick="vote('e/mit', 0, 'swap')"  ></button>
    </div></div>
     </div>
```

This is the voting system which is working fine.
with this style

```
vote-up button{

height: 32px;
width: 32px;
border: 0;
background: url("upvote.png");
}
 .vote-down button
{
height: 32px;
width: 32px;
border: 0;
background: url("downvote.png");
}
```

up to this each post has up and down arrow. when the user clicks the button the image of button should change, for that i have written this function in jquery

```
function vote(id, vote, userid){
if(!logged)
{
    alert("You must be logged in to vote");
}
else {
    if(vote==1){
    $("#up-"+id).css({'background', 'url("upvoted.png")'});
    $("#down-"+id).css('background', 'url("downvote.png")');

        $("#up-"+id).attr('disabled', true);
        $("#down-"+id).attr('disabled', false);

        }

    else {$("#down-"+id).css('background', 'url("downvoted.png")');
        $("#up-"+id).css('background', 'url("upvote.png")');

        $("#down-"+id).attr('disabled', true);
        $("#up-"+id).attr('disabled', false);
    }}
```

the "downvoted.png" and "upvoted.png" stores the images which are to be places in place of the former images when user clicks the button.

When i click the buttons the images are not changing.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: the image does not change after clicking the buttons

Comment: please create a jsbin / jsfiddle demo page

Comment: I have imported blue images instead of original arrows and if user clicks it it should turn red   https://jsfiddle.net/zLjpjmr1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `.css` method incorrectly.  You need to have colons not commas between your attribute and the applier.  Currently you have:

```
.css({'background', 'url("upvoted.png")'});
```

And you need to update it to:

```
.css({'background':'url("upvoted.png")'});
```

Or remove the brackets since you are only updating one style:

```
.css('background', 'url("upvoted.png")');
```

In addition you might be running into an issue with jQuery finding the Id since it has a slash in it.  If you run into this issue use the following as your selector instead:

```
$("button[id*='down-" +id + "']")
```

And here is a working codepen:

http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/EZvYpQ

Comment: still same results

Comment: @SwapnilGoyal sorry, my id syntax was wrong.  Try again with new id target and few my code pen for a working version.

Comment: @SwapnilGoyal glad to hear it.  For future reference all your issues were present in the developer console.  If you aren't familiar with it read up on it.  Using it is a developers best friend.  Especially with JavaScript/jQuery.  Here is some info about Chrome's version: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/